# how to put a time of execution to a container?

Tags: docker

I execute:

```
docker run --stop-signal=9 --stop-timeout=30 --name=test test
```

> but this does not kill the container, it does not do anything!

*from the Manual Docker Run:*

> **Stop container with signal (--stop-signal)**
>
> The --stop-signal flag sets the system call signal that will be sent to the container to exit. This signal can be a valid unsigned number that matches a position in the kernel’s syscall table, for instance 9, or a signal name in the format SIGNAME, for instance SIGKILL.
>
> **Stop container with timeout (--stop-timeout)**
>
> The --stop-timeout flag sets the timeout (in seconds) that a pre-defined (see --stop-signal) system call signal that will be sent to the container to exit. After timeout elapses the container will be killed with SIGKILL.

*How is this used correctly?*

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there aren't any docker flags to run a container for a specified time. 
As you quoted the command you execute sets the signal sent to the main process of the container when docker stops (in your case `SIGKILL`).

If you want to run the container for some time and then stop it you could use the `timeout` utility that runs a command with a time limit:

```
timeout --signal=SIGTERM 5  docker run --rm test
```

The command, on timeout (5 seconds), sends the `SIGTERM` signal to the docker process which propagates it to the running service. Additionally, you could use the `--kill-after duration` flag to force the container to stop if it's still running after the initial signal was sent. Hope it helps.

Comment: See this [link](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#options)